# Q: Determination of Basis Vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

Given the Matrix:
$$A =
\begin{bmatrix}
0.44 & 0.19 & 0.71 & 0.66 & 0.96 & 0.75\\
0.38 & 0.49 & 0.75 & 0.16 & 0.34 & 0.26\\
0.77 & 0.45 & 0.28 & 0.12 & 0.59 & 0.51\\
0.80 & 0.65 & 0.68 & 0.50 & 0.22 & 0.70
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Do the columns of $A$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$? Do they form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^6$?

The $\text{rank}(A) = 4$ and there are 6 columns, so the columns of $A$ are not a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$

The columns of $A$ are also not a basis for $\mathbb{R}^6$ because none of the columns of $A$ belong to $\mathbb{R}^6$

**Questions:**

Would the rows of $A$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^6$? No, because the $\text{Rank}(A) = 4$?

What is a scenario (if any) is there that the dimension (number of basis vectors) of a basis set $\neq$ the number of elements in each basis vector?

My thought here would be something related to the null space. For example, $$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -4 & 3 & -1 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4
\end{bmatrix}
= [ 0 ]
$$
where each null space basis vector would be in $\mathbb{R}^4$ (have 4 components) but the dimension of the set would be 3 (3 basis vectors in total). Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: The number of vectors in a basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$ must be $n$ (the number of elements in a vector). In general, the number of vectors in a basis for a vector space $V$ is equal to the dimension of $V$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth is that only true when not talking about the null space? The basis of the null space of the provided $1x4$ vector has 3 columns (3 vectors) and 4 rows (4 elements in each)

Comment: You keep saying that the rank of $A$ is four. Have you actually computed this, or do you really mean that its rank is _at most_ four?

Comment: Any proper subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ has fewer than $n$ elements in a basis. The null space of a matrix is but one example of this.

Comment: The fact that the columns aren’t a basis for $\mathbb R^4$ has almost nothing to do with the rank of the matrix. Per the definition of dimension, no set of $\gt4$ elements of $\mathbb R^4$ can be linearly independent.